# Cruise Control.NET, NUnit integration

Tags: nunit, controls, cruisecontrol.net

I currently have a code base which has NUnit tests organised into suites. We currently have a build task on our CC box which runs all of the tests in one CC project.

Is there a way we can configure CC.Net to allow us to individually run the different test suites from the dashboard.

Something along the lines of a list of all the suites and a button next to each to run those tests.

The only way I can think of doing it now is to set each suite up as its own project and control them all from the top level dashboard, but we have alot of test suites and this complicates adding more.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no other solution than creating a separate project for each test suite.

- How could CCNET be aware of something like a test suite? What about different implementations of test suites?
- For CCNET a project is atomic i.e., a project is the smallest available element you can run and evaluate the results for.